# Asp.net MVC Multiline Form Control/ Textbox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to make the `input class= form control` field bigger and multi-line. I managed to do something similar in my last project but have deleted it and forgotten how to do it. Pretty much a text box but when I use text area it won't allow "asp for"

```
<label asp-for="Incident_Detail" class="control-label"></label>
<input asp-for="Incident_Detail" class="form-control" />
<span asp-validation-for="Incident_Detail" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the self-closing. Just try:

`<textarea asp-for="Incident_Detail" class="form-control"></textarea>`

*Note: You really should change this kind of property (size, width, height, etc...) from CSS. It allows you have responsive layouts, and make the whole solution/project a lot easier to maintain. Alternatively you could use `rows` for height and `cols` for width: `<textarea asp-for="Incident_Detail" class="form-control" rows="4" cols="100" />`*

*Note 2: The self-closing is currently (html 5) invalid html markup for some elements (including `textarea`). Since MVC Tag Helpers doesn't override what is in your cshtml file, the output end up messed up.*

Comment: When I use <textarea> it collects all the code below it into the text box

Comment: Brilliant! I had something similar in my old project but I reformatted my PC and forgot to back that specific project up lol.

Comment: @Daniel634 hehe, that happens... Really glad I could help! Please do not forget to mark my answer as accepted, and if you think i deserve it, I would be very glad if you upvote my answer : )

Comment: I accepted the answer. Tried to vote it up but keeps reverting back to 0 from my end LOL.

Comment: @Daniel634 that's ok. just glad we solved your problem :). cheers!